# How to change name under launcer icon

Tags: android, eclipse, label

I did not find a precise answer to understand how to change the name under a launcer icon of and android app (with Eclipse).

I tried editing "@string/app_name" in application (manifest), but it does not work.
And now in the MainActivity.java it gives me the error "R cannot be resolved to a variable" 
in this line:  `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);`

It gives me back this error also if write back "app_name" in @string/ inside application.
I'm going crazy.

Comment: check with the solution I have posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open `res/values/strings.xml`

change this line,

```
<string name="app_name">default app name</string>
```

with your desired app name

```
<string name="app_name">your desired name</string>
```

Don't make changes in the `manifest` file.

Comment: That's cool.
But I still have the problem with the Manifest...don't know why.

Comment: @volso try to clean your project and then also it showing errors then paste your manifest code. I will try to correct that. Thanks.

Comment: I meant, the Activity (not Manifest)
Why this error? "R cannot be resolved to a variable"

`public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {


 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
  return true;
 }

}`

Comment: @volso I think you made some changes with this line from strings.xml `<string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>`. Or from your activity remove `import R.xx.xx` if it exists.

Comment: After i cleaned the second time the project, now it goes.
Thank you for your help Pratik.

Answer (score 7):

Look for `android:label` inside `<Activity>` that has

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

inside `<intent-filter>` and change its value:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Activity_1_1_Splash"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And if you want to change the resource value, [@pratik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14755259/156869) will guide you.

Comment: Still have the error about "R":

 `<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.volso.anguillaramobile2.MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>`

Answer (score 2):

if you want to change app name under launcher icon then change this `android:label="@string/app_name"` 
inside your Main Launcher activity tag

```
        <activity android:name="com.test.app"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" >
                  <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                  </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

And if you want to change app name inside

> Settings -> Application manager -> downloaded

where you have all installed applications then change this `android:label="@string/app_name"`
inside application tag

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

            ........

        <activity android:name="com.test.app" >
        </activity>

             .......

 </application>
```